# Issue when I create a big array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory

Can someone tell me why my laptop gets stuck if I create an array like this in Swift 4:

```
let numbers = Array(0...Int32.max)
```

Comment: Think about how many numbers need to be put in that array. Why do you want an array with over 2 billion numbers in it?

Answer (score 5):

This is not a problem with either Swift or your laptop. This is the matter of how to use it properly.

For signed integer types, this value is (2 ^ (bitWidth - 1)) - 1. So Int32.max = 2^31-1 = 2,147,483,647.

32 bits = 4 bytes. So you have 2 billion * 4 = 8 billion bytes ~~ 7,700 GB.

Does your laptop have enough RAM?